# Spring Boot and Keycloak - GrantedAuthority always coming back empty

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I've setup a REST API I'm trying to secure with Keycloak, and running everything in a local Docker compose.  The REST API is running on host/service `rest-api`, Keycloak is running on `auth-service`, and there's a proxy container in front of both (so anything starting with /auth goes to Keycloak and anything else goes to the API).

Security Configuration - I've tried a few things, but currently it sits as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration
        extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration(
                "/**",
                new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()
        );
        return source;
    }

    /**
     * Global configuration.
     *
     * @param auth Authentication Manager Builder
     * @throws Exception If security can't be configured
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper =
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider =
                keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                grantedAuthorityMapper
        );
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl()
        );
    }
}
```

and then there's a simple controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequestMapping("/api/v3/auth")
public class AuthController {
    /**
     * Logger.
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    AuthController() {
        LOGGER.info("AuthController Constructor.");
    }
...
    /**
     * Checks/initiates a user login.
     *
     * @return Information about the current user's auth status
     */
    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_user")
    @GetMapping(
            value = "/login1",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> login1() {
        final Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("status", "OK");

        final Authentication authentication =
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        final List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
            roles.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        response.put(
                "Current user roles",
                "[" + String.join(",", roles) + "]"
        );

        return response;
    }
}
```

The `@RolesAllowed` annotation does initiate the Keycloak integration.  I'm taken to the login page, I'm allowed to log in, and I'm passed back to the REST application at /sso/login, and that response sets the JWT I would expect:

```
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_ADAPTER_STATE=eyJhbGciOi...
```

Using https://jwt.io/ to debug, that token looks good to me, specifically:

```
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization",
      "user"
    ]
  },
```

However, when I then get directed back to the login page, I receive a 403 forbidden.  So I cooked up a second method in that same controller:

```
    @GetMapping(
            value = "",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> read() {
        final Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("status", "OK");

        final Authentication authentication =
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        response.put(
                "AUTHENTICATION NAME",
                authentication.getName()
        );
        response.put(
                "AUTHENTICATION PRINCIPAL",
                authentication.getPrincipal().toString()
        );
        response.put(
                "AUTHENTICATION AUTHORITIES",
                authentication.getAuthorities().toString()
        );

        int i = 0;
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
            response.put(
                    "AUTHORITY-" + i++,
                    authority.getAuthority()
            );
        }

        return response;
    }
```

The output of that looks like:

```
{
  "AUTHENTICATION PRINCIPAL": "<GUID I expect>",
  "AUTHENTICATION NAME": "<GUID I expect>",
  "status": "OK",
  "AUTHENTICATION AUTHORITIES": "[]"
}
```

So...  I'm clearly getting an authentication JWT back from Keycloak, and it seems like Spring is trying to do the right thing with it.  But the GrantedAuthority list is always empty, so I'm always getting a 403.

Any suggestions on what's awry here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course, with all that, it comes down to one config line:

```
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

Changing that to false pulls from the realm mappings instead of the resource mappings, and I'm good.